# Find on Page using shell

Tags: ms-access, vba, sendkeys

I'm using VBA in MS Access. I'm trying search through ie tabs (15 of them) bring the found tab to the foreground, maximise it, then find on page a string i'm searching for. I can find the tab using the code below but its not maximising the window and nor are the send keys working to find on page. Is there a way using the shell to do this?

```
Option Compare Database

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
               (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
               (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
#End If



Private Sub P2_Click()
Dim sURL As String
Dim strSearch As String
Dim SWs As Object


sURL = CStr(Me.tblOdds_1_sURL)
strSearch = Mid(Me.P2, 1, 5)

 'get windows
 Set SWs = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

  For Each ow In SWs.windows


    If ow = "Internet Explorer" _
    And sURL = Trim(ow.Document.Location) Then

    SetForegroundWindow ow.hWnd

    SendKeys "^f", False
    SendKeys strSearch, False
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", False
    SendKeys "{ESC}", False

End If
Next ow

Set SWs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code seems basically correct. First you should use [debug](http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/vbacode/debug.asp) in the loop if ow.Document.Location returns a comparable value for your if statement. Second, you cannot just set IE to foreground, you also need to activate the correct tab. Third you should check if you use separate windows for each Tab in Internet Exploerer. That could be another Problem. Fourth `SendKeys "{ESC}"` closes the search tab in Explorer imediately. You cannot see if it is activated or not. Remove it for test purpose.

Comment: I know that I don't  use separate windows for each Tab. What is the code to activate the correct tab? I shall comment out SendKeys "{ESC}" . Thanks.

Comment: Tried using AppActivate ow.Name  but because the window name is "Internet Explorer" it just opened to the first tab, not the tab. I wanted AppActivate to  activate the correct tab in the if statement.

Comment: So no-one has a any ideas?

Comment: You could try the answer of 1SkyWalker to this [Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89393961-af9c-49ae-9159-927ea75a9174/vba-activate-a-tab-in-internet-explorer?forum=isvvba). If you find a solution, please add it here.